# Creating a C++ std::tuple projection function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I am looking for a projection function for `std::tuple`. I.e., the function receives a list of integers as template parameters and returns a tuple that only has the values at these indexes.

For example, consider I have a tuple `tuple<int,String,char,float> t`, then a call to `project<1,3>(t)` would result in a tuple of type `tuple<String,float>`.

Of course, the key seems to be recursive templates. However, I am unable to get it to work. I tried starting by declaring a struct to calculate the return type of a projection operation. Even that fails. Here is what I tried:

```
template<typename T, size_t... indexes>
class Projection{
};

// Specialization for no index => Empty tuple
template<>
template<typename... T>
class Projection<std::tuple<T...>>{
   typedef std::tuple<T...> InputTuple;
   typedef std::tuple<> Tuple;
};

// Specialization for one or more parameters
template<size_t Index1, size_t... others>
template<typename... T>
class Projection<std::tuple<T...>,Index1,others...>{
    typedef std::tuple<T...> InputTuple;

    // The type of a projection with one column less
    typedef Projection<std::tuple<T...>,others...> TupleMinusOne;

    // The result type is the catenation of TupleMinusOne plus the column projected in this     step
    typedef decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::get<Index1>(InputTuple())),typename TupleMinusOne::Tuple())) Tuple;
};
```

This compiles. The base case with the empty tuple also works, i.e.:

```
Projection<std::tuple<int,std::string>>::Tuple t;
```

results in `t` being an empty tuple. However, the recursion case does not compile:

```
Projection<std::tuple<int,std::string>,1>::Tuple t;
```

I get the following error:

```
Test.cpp:79:1: error: ‘Tuple’ is not a member of ‘Projection<std::tuple<int, float>, 1ul>’
```

so it seems that the recursive case is not recognized, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive templates are very rarely necessary; a [pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) is usually clearer and simpler.  In this case just use `tuple_element`:

```
template<typename T, size_t... indexes>
class Projection{
public:
    using Tuple = std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<indexes, T>::type...>;
};
```

Ditto for `project`:

```
template<size_t... indexes, typename T>
auto project(const T &t) -> typename Projection<T, indexes...>::Tuple {
    return typename Projection<T, indexes...>::Tuple(std::get<indexes>(t)...);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about pack expension, that seems much easier, thanks. However, your class does not compile. When I add it and try instanciating it using `Projection<std::tuple<int,std::string>,1>::Tuple t;`, I receive around 10 errors.

Comment: @gexicide sorry, got the arguments the wrong way round. Fixed.

Comment: The class works now, thanks! But the function still does not compile when calling it like this: `std::tuple<int,int,float,std::string> t {1,1,4.5,"bla"};
   std::tuple<int,float> f= project<1,2,std::tuple<int,int,float,std::string>>(t);`

Comment: @gexicide leave out the last argument to `project`: `project<1,2>(t)` - there's no way to supply an argument after a variadic list, it has to be inferred.

Comment: Didn't know about that, now it works like a charm, thank you very much, very quick and elaborate help!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

```
#define Return(ret) decltype(ret) { return ret; }

template<std::size_t... Is, typename T>
auto project(const T& t) -> Return(std::make_tuple(std::get<Is>(t)...))
```